# ChatScript Bot on Localhost

Tags: php, html, localhost, chatbot, chatscript

I have created a chatbot using chatscript. It works perfectly in .cmd when I execute a chatscript.exe program. 
Now I am trying to run the chatbot the browser using xampp. 
I have done the following steps:

1. I have installed XAMPP on C drive.
2. In XAMPP > HTDOCS folder I have added the Chatscript folder in it.
3. I am using Better web interface provided by chatscript.
4. When I try to run the index.php file, the bot doesn't reply.

Please find below code used in the web interface.
Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> CHATSCRIPT SERVER
    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      #responseHolder {
        min-width: 600px;
        min-height: 300px;
        width: 80%;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: auto;
        margin: 10px auto;
        background-color: pink;

      }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body class="bgimg">
    <div id="responseHolder"></div>
    <form id="frmChat" action="#">
    <p>
      Enter your message below:
    </p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="txtUser" name="user" size="20" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="send" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Message:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="message" id="txtMessage" size="70" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="send" value="Send Value" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var botName = 'rose';       // change this to your bot name

// declare timer variables
var alarm = null;
var callback = null;
var loopback = null;

$(function(){
    $('#frmChat').submit(function(e){
    // this function overrides the form's submit() method, allowing us to use AJAX calls to communicate with the ChatScript server
    e.preventDefault();  // Prevent the default submit() method
    var name = $('#txtUser').val();
    if (name == '') {
        alert('Please provide your name.');
        document.getElementById('txtUser').focus();
    }
    var chatLog = $('#responseHolder').html();
    var youSaid = '<strong>' + name + ':</strong> ' + $('#txtMessage').val() + "<br>\n";
    update(youSaid);
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    sendMessage(data);
    $('#txtMessage').val('').focus();
    });

    // any user typing cancels loopback or callback for this round 
    $('#txtMessage').keypress(function(){
          window.clearInterval(loopback);
          window.clearTimeout(callback);
        });
});

function sendMessage(data){ //Sends inputs to the ChatScript server, and returns the response-  data - a JSON string of input information
$.ajax({
    url: 'ui.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: data,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(response){
        processResponse(parseCommands(response));
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
        alert('oops? Status = ' + status + ', error message = ' + error + "\nResponse = " + xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
}

function parseCommands(response){ // Response is data from CS server. This processes OOB commands sent from the CS server returning the remaining response w/o oob commands

    var len  = response.length;
    var i = -1;
    while (++i < len )
    {
        if (response.charAt(i) == ' ' || response.charAt(i) == '\t') continue; // starting whitespace
        if (response.charAt(i) == '[') break;   // we have an oob starter
        return response;                        // there is no oob data 
    }
    if ( i == len) return response; // no starter found
    var user = $('#txtUser').val();

    // walk string to find oob data and when ended return rest of string
    var start = 0;
    while (++i < len )
    {
        if (response.charAt(i) == ' ' || response.charAt(i) == ']') // separation
        {
            if (start != 0) // new oob chunk
            {
                var blob = response.slice(start,i);
                start = 0;

                var commandArr = blob.split('=');
                if (commandArr.length == 1) continue;   // failed to split left=right

                var command = commandArr[0]; // left side is command 
                var interval = (commandArr.length > 1) ? commandArr[1].trim() : -1; // right side is millisecond count
                if (interval == 0)  /* abort timeout item */
                {
                    switch (command){
                        case 'alarm':
                            window.clearTimeout(alarm);
                            alarm = null;
                            break;
                        case 'callback':
                            window.clearTimeout(callback);
                            callback = null;
                            break;
                        case 'loopback':
                            window.clearInterval(loopback);
                            loopback = null;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else if (interval == -1) interval = -1; // do nothing
                else
                {
                    var timeoutmsg = {user: user, send: true, message: '[' + command + ' ]'}; // send naked command if timer goes off 
                    switch (command) {
                        case 'alarm':
                            alarm = setTimeout(function(){sendMessage(timeoutmsg );}, interval);
                            break;
                        case 'callback':
                            callback = setTimeout(function(){sendMessage(timeoutmsg );}, interval);
                            break;
                        case 'loopback':
                            loopback = setInterval(function(){sendMessage(timeoutmsg );}, interval);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } // end new oob chunk
            if (response.charAt(i) == ']') return response.slice(i + 2); // return rest of string, skipping over space after ] 
        } // end if
        else if (start == 0) start = i; // begin new text blob
    } // end while
    return response;    // should never get here
 }

function update(text){ // text is  HTML code to append to the 'chat log' div. This appends the input text to the response div
    var chatLog = $('#responseHolder').html();
    $('#responseHolder').html(chatLog + text);
    var rhd = $('#responseHolder');
    var h = rhd.get(0).scrollHeight;
    rhd.scrollTop(h);
}

function processResponse(response) { // given the final CS text, converts the parsed response from the CS server into HTML code for adding to the response holder div
    var botSaid = '<strong>' + botName + ':</strong> ' + response + "<br>\n";
    update(botSaid);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

ui.php

```
<?php

//  =============  user values ====
$host = "localhost";  //  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< YOUR CHATSCRIPT SERVER IP ADDRESS OR HOST-NAME GOES HERE
$port = 8080;          // <<<<<<< your port number if different from 1024
$bot  = "rose";    
// <<<<<<< desired botname, or "" for default bot
//=========================

// Please do not change anything below this line.
$null = "\x00";
$postVars = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
extract($postVars);

if (isset($send))
{
     if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
       $userip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
        $userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }   
    $msg = $userip.$null.$bot.$null.$message.$null;

    if(!$fp=fsockopen($host,$port,$errstr,$errno,300))
    {
        trigger_error('Error opening socket',E_USER_ERROR);
    }    
    // write message to socket server
    fputs($fp,$msg);
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $ret .= fgets($fp, 512);
    }

    fclose($fp);
    exit($ret);
}
```

Please find below screenshot of the issue:
[Issue while accessing chatbot on localhost:8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUd9z.png)

I am having difficulty in connecting my chatscript server and localhost. Please let me know what should I change in UI.php so that bot will send the reply.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you start the CS in server mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one error in the UI.php file. The `$ret` variable breaks because it is not declared. If you add `$ret = '';` just above `fputs` the code should work:

```
 // write message to socket server
    $ret = '';
    fputs($fp,$msg);
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $ret .= fgets($fp, 512);
    }

    fclose($fp);
    exit($ret);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the $ret correction, upon running in XAMPP, as the web host is Apache, so client uses port 8080 or 8088,  upon using CS over Web.
ChatScript as server, start the ChatScript system with using port 1024 ( or user-defined)  is needed.
Furthermore, Harry Bot  is also called in index.php file, change to Rose as in ui.php file.
I have CS responses after doing these.